# Receive data from Audio jack in windows phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I wasn't sure if this questions belongs here, but I'm completely new to this topic so hopefully you can help me out.

I have some kind of hardware which will be connected to my windows phone (wp7/wp8) through the audio jack. It sends some data in an audio format. I would like to retrieve this data through code. How can I do this?

Any source code or samples would be appreciated.

Comment: You do realize you're going to be trying to feed data into an Audio out jack, right? Meaning the jack on WP (and pretty much every other phone) is not meant to receive a signal and you're likely going to damage it.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to post an answer so I could elaborate on my comment.

The problem with what you're trying to do is that the jack on Windows phones is an output jack. I haven't seen any that support microphone input. This means the jack is meant to generate a signal, but never to receive one. That means that you would never be able to attach a device and send audio data into the phone through that jack. It's completely missing any hardware that would allow you to interpret what you send into it, and honestly you risk frying the jack or worse, the phone itself.

Perhaps the best course of action would be to look at different ways to push that audio data into the phone. I can't really guide you on that because it's a very open course of action that depends on your specific needs.

Comment: I know that the iPhone and Android devices, for example can accept input data as `PayPal Here` and other apps use. Isn't that possible with the Windows Phone and pretty much any other phone?

Comment: None of the Windows phones that I've looked at support microphone input to their audio jack, so I don't think this will work on Windows Phone. Notice that Square, Paypal Here, etc are not released for Windows phone.

Comment: @steveg89: Thanks for your input. But for your information the square have implemented the same, please check with this link http://wmpoweruser.com/windows-phone-finally-gets-a-square-like-credit-card-reader/